# Randomizing My Array elements

Tags: php, mysql

How do i randomize my array elements and limit number of items to be displayed to 5

My code is:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
  $new_array[] = $row; 
}
  echo '<pre>'; print_r(($new_array));
```

Comment: use `shuffle` to randomize, and loop from `0` to `5`. Simple google would have solved that one for you.

Comment: post your whole code, since you're pulling from a mysql source randomise the result set in query `ORDER BY `field` RAND` type thing you can also use `LIMIT` to limit the amount of results returned ie: `LIMIT 0,5` will pull out only 5 results

Comment: In what way does this differ from your previous question? [Displaying and Randomising php Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469360/displaying-and-randomising-php-arrays)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-slice.php

Comment: um. array_rand($new_array, 5);

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution...

`array_rand($array, 5);`

[PHP array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
shuffle($array);
$pointer = 0;
foreach($array as $value) {
    if($pointer > 4) break;
    echo $value;
    $pointer++
}
```

`shuffle` will randomize your array, then you start a pointer at 0 and increment it in your foreach loop, if you the pointer is more than 4 you break the foreach loop

as another solution, you could use a for loop

```
shuffle($array);
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo $array[$i];
}
```

and one more solution for limiting, since you're pulling the array for your database by a query, you can limit the number of rows returned by a number you choose by adding `LIMIT 5` at the end of your query.